# I am trying to delete a pin on map, stored in the documents directory, but I get this error The file “SavedLocations” couldn’t be opened

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to delete a pin on map, I have several of them on the map stored in the documents directory.I want to delete only a single pin at time, but once I call my delete method, I get this error- The file “SavedLocations” couldn’t be opened. How do I delete a single pin saved in the documents directory? Please help, Thank you.

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
//Load method
func loadData() {
    print("loaded data")
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedLocations")

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: filename)
        locations = try JSONDecoder().decode([CodableMKPointAnnotation].self, from: data)

    } catch {
        print("Unable to load saved data")
    }
}
//Save method
func saveData() {
    print("saved data")

    do {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedLocations")
       // print(filename)
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.locations)
        try data.write(to: filename, options: [.atomicWrite, .completeFileProtection])

    } catch {
        print("Unable to save data")
    }

}
//Delete method
func delete() {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedLocations")
    print("Pin deleted")
    print(filename)

    do {
        let items = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: filename, includingPropertiesForKeys: .none, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        print(items)

        for item in items {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: item)
            print(item)
        }

    } catch let error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this method to:

```swift
func delete() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedLocations")
    print("Pin deleted")
    print(filename)

    do {
        let items = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: filename, includingPropertiesForKeys: .none, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        print(items)

        if (newArray.count > 0){
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: items[0])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```